# Add an element to another existing entity using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository-pattern, code-first

Let's take this scenario:

- I want to add a task to project.
- The project exist already.
- Task will be added as new entity and attached to the project.
- A project can have one or many tasks.

This is the way I do it in now my repository :

```
public void AddTaskToProject(Project ProjectToUpdate,Task TaskToAdd)
{
    using (var context = new myContext())
    {
        var project= context.Projects.First(x => x.Id == projectToUpdate.Id);
        project.Tasks.Add(taskToAdd);
        context.Tasks.Add(taskToAdd);

        SaveContextChange(context);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to avoid as much call to database as I did?

The ideal for me, is to update the project, and then call only an update for the project entity ? is there a way to do that ?

This is the generic update I have:

```
public virtual void Update(params T[] items)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            context.Entry(item).State =EntityState.Modified;
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
public void AddTaskToProject(Project projectToUpdate,Task taskToAdd)
{
  using (var context = new myContext())
  {
    var project = new Project() { ProjectId = projectToUpdate.Id };
    context.Projects.Attach(project);
    project.Tasks.Add(taskToAdd);
    context.SaveChanges();
   }
 }
```